# Ideal associated to a point in projective geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question for you (I think ?).

We take a point $a \in \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{K})$.
I know that $I(a)  (X_0,...,X_n) $ since $P \in I(a)$ must be 
homogenous. So $I(a)$ is not a maximal ideal. But can we calculate explicitly $I(a)$ ?

Can we found polynomials such that $V(P_1,...,P_r)=\{a\} ?$ In the affine 
space, it's very easy to see that $P_1=X_1-a_1, ..., P_n=X_n-a_n$ works but in the projective space, it doesn't work...

Cordially,
Doeup

Comment: Any closed set can be defined by a system of homogeneous equations. So just homogenise your affine equations?

Comment: I homogenise the equations and i have $X_0-a_0X_0,X_1-a_1X_0,..., X_n-a_nX_0$. But $[0:1:1:...:1] \not \in (X_0,X_1-X_0,..., X_n-X_0)$

Comment: Have you tried building up from toy examples? In $\mathbb{P}^1$, if $a = (s:t)$ then $V(tx-sy) = a$. Now try $\mathbb{P}^2$ to give you the idea for $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$I(a)=\langle a_iX_j-a_jX_i\vert i,j=0,\cdots,n\rangle$$